Overleaf Github Synchronization Error
I get this error when I try to push to or pull from github: "Must supply either tree.sha or tree.content. Request will be rejected if both are present." How could I fix this? There doesn't seem to be any explanation beyond this.

If this is from trying to sync git and Overleaf, I think you would be better served by asking Overleaf's tech support.

I just contacted Overleaf about this as I was getting the same error. Their answer was that they usually see this with very large files, around 50MB, but recently they have also seen it with ~40MB files. This limitation is why Overleaf's file size limit is 50MB (ref).
Their recommendation was the following:

Only include the files needed for compilation
The compile process should only be limited to typesetting. Tables, graphs, etc., should be ideally generated outside of the latex compilation process.
Instead of syncing a large git repository, use submodules
Or, instead of using Github Sync, keep the Overleaf project synced with Github setting up a workflow that uses the git integration (link), copying the tex project to a small local repo that is synchronised with the larger Github one.

